# DataArrays in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying out Julia and the DataArray package. I want to initialize, with zeros, a data array of a size given by an integer stored in a variable 'n'. However, I get an error message "ERROR: n not defined" (even though it clearly seems to be).

The following is a small example:

```
using DataArrays
n = 8
@data(zeros(Float64,n))
```

which for me produces the above error message. (Note that

```
using DataArrays
@data(zeros(Float64,8))
```

does work.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 8
float64(DataArray(zeros(Float64 ,n)))
```

Will get you where you're going. The `@data` macro kind of sucks and the only use I can think for it is when writing tests if you want to say something like

```
x = @data([1,2,3,NA])
```

Normally the list constructor will crap on you. However this does also work:

```
x = float64(DataArray(Any[1,2,3,NA]))
```

So, I don't know. Stay away from that `@data` macro. Macros in general have a hard time seeing your local variables or functions and variables from other Modules. It's a problem that can clearly be worked around since `@show` mostly works, but many macros have this and other problems. Macros in general are kind of suspect.

Comment: I agree with Michael that the `@data` macro needs a lot of work. But I also wouldn't use his proposed solution, which creates a `DataArray{Any}`, which is almost certainly not what you want. The easiest solution is to do `@data(zeros($n))`.

Comment: Thanks Michael and John; I do not have a programming background (only worked extensively with R thus far) so I have been oblivious to problems with macros.

Comment: @JohnMylesWhite So that's why I keep having to `convert` my `DataArray`s. Fixed: `float64(DataArray(Any[1., 2., NA]))`

Comment: @MichaelFox: You shouldn't have to do that. The `@data` macro is just buggy. FWIW, it's better than the previous buggy solution that it replaced.